# Vercel deploy is not looking like my local version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

Hi my Nextjs deployed website in Vercel looks different from my local version. I've already played around with different values and ways of rearranging the layout but never get the same result I see on my local machine when I run in dev mode, I also have built the project in my machine and it displays well just when Vercel does the build it turns into a different layout. why is that and how can i solve it?

```
"use client";
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/free-mode";
import "swiper/css/navigation";
import "swiper/css/thumbs";
import { FreeMode, Navigation, Thumbs } from "swiper";
import { urlFor } from "@/lib/sanityClient";
import { LanguageContext } from "@/app/context/languangeContext";

export default function RenovationSlide({ imagePairs }) {


  const { translations } = useContext(LanguageContext);



  return (
    
      <Swiper
        style={{ "--swiper-navigation-color": "#172554", "--swiper-pagination-color": "#172554" }}
        loop={true}
        navigation={true}
        modules={[FreeMode, Navigation]}
        className="w-full h-[100vh] "

      >
        {imagePairs.map((pair, index) => (
          <SwiperSlide key={index}> 
              <div className="w-full h-full flex flex-col justify-center items-center pb-10 md:px-20">
                <div className="w-full h-[50vh] p-2 md:p-10">
                  <h1 className="font-semibold text-xl text-center pb-5 ">{translations.slideBefore}</h1>
                  <img src={urlFor(pair.before).fit('clip').width(2000).height(1000).url()} className="w-full h-full object-contain" />
                </div>
                <div className="w-full h-[50vh] p-2 md:p-10">
                  <h1 className="font-semibold text-xl text-center pb-5 ">{translations.slideAfter}</h1>
                  <img src={urlFor(pair.after).fit('clip').width(2000).height(1000).url()} className="w-full h-full object-contain" />
                </div>
              </div>
          </SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
  );
}
```

**Local version:**

[image]

**Vercel build:**

[image]